# LDAP Authentication in Windows 8.1 Apps

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm working on a **Windows 8.1 app** which goes through **LDAP authentication**.
But I see, there's no **System.DirectoryServices** available for WinRT apps.

---

Can anyone help me with a work around and links to the same ?

Comment: @AtmaneELBOUACHRI : Not yet.

Answer (score 1):

I wish you had included more information. But I will assume you are wanting to authenticate against Active Directory in Azure, you can use the ADAL SDK for Windows Runtime.

Here's some training on the library.

> http://channel9.msdn.com/series/Developing-Universal-Windows-Apps-with-C-and-XAML/08

Best of luck!

Comment: No. The active directory is not on Azure.

Comment: if AD is not in azure ?